# Helm using ternary with condition checking if list is empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using ternary operand to set values to a variable in my helm template. I am unable to get the condition to check if a list is defined.

`{{- $environment_names:= ternary $service.environments $.Values.default.environment_names $service.environments }}`

> executing "root-app/templates/applications.yaml" at <$service.environments>: wrong type for value; expected bool; got interface {}

is there a possibility to convert this map to boolean? I tried `bool` and `length`which are not functions in helm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how I could make it working

```
{{- $environment_names:= ternary $service.environments $.Values.default.environment_names (hasKey $service "environments") }}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can use the [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) template function here: if `$service.environments` is defined, use its value, but if not (if it's zero, nil, empty string, or otherwise "falsey") use the default value.

```
{{- $environment_names := $service.environments | default $.Values.default.environment_names }}
```